# How to run parted mklabel in a script without user prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, partition, parted

I am trying to write a bashscript that will re-partition a drive using the parted utility. Since it is running in a script, I would like parted to not prompt the user for input (or alternatively, have a method to answer those prompts).

Initially, I tried passing the '-s' or '--script' option to parted but it does not do work the way I expected. When I try running `parted $DRIVE -s mklabel gpt` in the script, I expect that parted will answer the three prompts with 'i', 'y', and 'i' (ignore, yes, ignore) to the warnings it gives. However, my script stops execution with the following message: `Error: Partition(s) on /dev/nvme1 are being used.`

Running that command manually shows that message and allows me to pass the response 'i' to ignore the warning and continue. From some googling, I gathered that parted will go with the default response when running with the -s option. I assume that when this warning appears, the default option is to cancel so as to not accidentally ruin a drive.

When running the script without passing -s to parted, I get prompted at the terminal for input, and when given, the rest of the script runs fine. I then tried piping in the responses using echo like so `echo "i\ny\ni" | repart.sh` but that does not appear to work either.

Is there a way to override this default to get the desired behavior? If not, is there some other way to achieve this?

For context: the target machine running this script is running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Note: While I can install additional utilities that are not standard on Ubuntu, I would prefer not to.

EDIT: I have found a solution thanks to @chexum! I modified my script to called the wipefs utility before running parted: `wipefs -a -f $DRIVE` and then modified my parted command to pipe 'i' into it to answer the one remaining prompt: `yes "i" | parted $DRIVE mklabel gpt`. It now works completely automated. As a note to any future readers, using the wipefs utility carries its own risks if you are not careful, this solution worked well for my purposes but may not be well suited for others.

Comment: Manipulating partition tables are inherently dangerous, so it may be on purpose.  In lieu of an answer, however, if you know what you are doing(!) - you can also remove the previous partitions with wipefs on the main device beforehand.  This will also prevent any cleanup of the in-memory information of mounted/used partitions (cryptsetup, lvm)

Comment: `/dev/nvme1` is the device for the NVMe controller. The actual storage is within a NVMe *namespace*, typically `/dev/nvme1n1` since consumer-grade NVMe devices usually have just one namespace. To partition a NVMe device, you should use `/dev/nvme1n1`, not just `/dev/nvme1`. The partitions will be of the form `/dev/nvme1n1pN` where N is the partition number.

Comment: @telcoM I tried modifying my script to run the parted mklabel command with /dev/nvme1n1 instead of /dev/nvme1 but I get the same issue.

Comment: @chexum This is a very targeted used script so it should be okay to completely wipe the file system since all of that drive data can be recovered if things go south. I will try using the wipefs command first and see if that helps. Thank you!